# Laravel Escaping All HTML in Blade Template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I'm building a small CMS in Laravel and I tried to show the content (which is stored in the DB). It is showing the HTML tags instead of executing them. Its like there is an auto html_entity_decode for all printed data.

```php
<?php

class CmsController extends BaseController
{
    public function Content($name)
    {    
        $data = Pages::where('CID', '=', Config::get('company.CID'))
            ->where('page_name', '=', $name)
            ->first();

        return View::make('cms.page')->with('content', $data);
    }
}
```

I tried to print the content using the curly brace.

```php
{{ $content->page_desc }}
```

and triple curly brace.

```php
{{{ $content->page_desc }}}
```

And they give the same result. I need to execute those HTML tags instead of escaping them.

Comment: In latest version `ver-5.0` `{{...}}` and `{{{...}}}` both does this, what version do you have exactly ?

Comment: im using version 4.2

Comment: Then I'm not sure why `{{...}}` gives escaped result!

Comment: In `v-5`, use `{!!  !!}` for normal output (without esc).

Comment: Are they stored as "tags" or already escaped in the db? Because else I would see it like The Alpha, this should only be the case in `v5` of laravel

Comment: this is the first thing i checked before asking my question and yes they stored normally in the sql table

Comment: @Dr.Neo I've modified my answer. Maybe it will help you

Comment: The {!! !!} syntax definitely worked for me in Laravel 5.

Answer (score 192):

Change your syntax from `{{ }}` to `{!! !!}`.

As The Alpha said in a comment above (not an answer so I thought I'd post), in Laravel 5, the `{{ }}` (previously non-escaped output syntax) has changed to `{!! !!}`. Replace `{{ }}`  with `{!! !!}` and it should work.

Comment: Solved in my case!

Comment: worked like magic. Thanks!! Though I don't know why html_entity_decode didn't work.

Comment: @IvanTopolcic is there a way to extract the html coming back from an `@yield('content')` blade directive?

Comment: This is documented at https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade

Answer (score 18):

use this tag `{!! description text !!}`

Comment: This answer worked for my in Laravel 5.2. In the course of working on the problem, I also discovered that Illuminate/Support/helpers.php::529 runs `htmlentities()` if you don't use this syntax: `{!! !!}`.

Comment: Still works in Laravel 7 ...

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue. Thanks for the answers above, I solved my issue. If there are people facing the same problem, here is two way to solve it:

- You can use `{!! $news->body !!}`
- You can use traditional php openning (It is not recommended) like: `<?php echo $string ?>`

I hope it helps.

Comment: is there a way to extract the html coming back from an `@yield('content')` blade directive?

Answer (score 7):

Include the content in `{! <content> !}` .

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem with displaying HTML code in blade templates.

For test, you can add to routes.php only one route:

```
Route::get('/', function () {

        $data = new stdClass();
        $data->page_desc
            = '<strong>aaa</strong><em>bbb</em>
               <p>New paragaph</p><script>alert("Hello");</script>';

        return View::make('hello')->with('content', $data);
    }
);
```

and in `hello.blade.php` file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

{{ $content->page_desc }}

</body>
</html>
```

For the following code you will get output as on image

[image: Output]

So probably `page_desc` in your case is not what you expect. But as you see it can be potential dangerous if someone uses for example '` tag so you should probably in your route before assigning to blade template filter some tags

**EDIT**

I've also tested it with putting the same code into database:

```
Route::get('/', function () {

        $data = User::where('id','=',1)->first();

        return View::make('hello')->with('content', $data);
    }
);
```

Output is exactly the same in this case

**Edit2**

I also don't know if `Pages` is your model or it's a vendor model. For example it can have accessor inside:

```
public function getPageDescAttribute($value)
{
    return htmlspecialchars($value);
}
```

and then when you get `page_desc` attribute you will get modified `page_desc` with `htmlspecialchars`. So if you are sure that data in database is with raw html (not escaped) you should look at this `Pages` class

Comment: testing now Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in Laravel 10

```
{!! $blog->description !!}
```

Comment: Those tags will output what the user entered data saved to the database. This could include anything. Consider passing it through an HTML filter or purifier.

Answer (score -4):

{{html_entity_decode ($post->content())}} saved the issue for me with Laravel 4.0. Now My HTML content is interpreted as it should.

Comment: Yes, this solution actually works for laravel 4 - maybe someone know better solution for L4?

Comment: Since we are using laravel we should use {!! !!} which follows the Laravel syntax.