# how can I apply xss filter on output of laravel views?

Tags: laravel, xss

I know I can use {{{}}} for escape all html tags from output texts, but I want to escape only unsafe tags not all tags (for example I want to use br tag in the text)

Comment: View this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26023823/laravel-escaping-all-html-in-blade-template

Comment: Here discusses a similar problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26023823/laravel-escaping-all-html-in-blade-template

Comment: I saw both of them, I need an output filter that filters only dangerous codes, is there anything like that in laravel template views engine or I should implement it by myself.

Comment: @MohammadRezaEsmaeilzadeh You need to look up and use a solution that utilizes a whitelist, not a blacklist. You also need to filter attributes, as well as sanitize hrefs so that they only point to http/https. There's more to it, but you don't want to go down a road where you filter only dangerous tags... because almost any tag can be dangerous with attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely implement it by yourself. I'm assuming that the tags you want to escape are probably just `<script>` and `<iframe>`, however in my opinion it is more appropriate to remove entirely that content instead of keeping escaped content on your page for no reason.

You could use `regex` for simple substitution, something like

```
$html = preg_replace("/<iframe.*?>/", "", $html);
$html = preg_replace("/<script(.*?)>(.*?)<\/script>/", "", $html);
```

However it's considered **bad practice** because the perfect regex expression doesn't exist, so you could have a breach in your security.

A better idea would be using the PHP [DOMDocument](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) Parser. You can do something like this to remove script tags:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();

$doc->loadHTML($html);

$script_tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('script');

for ($i = 0; $i < $script_tags->length; $i++) {
    $script_tags->item($i)->parentNode->removeChild($script_tags->item($i));
}

$clean_html = $doc->saveHTML();
```