# Laravel Blade template sanitization

Tags: templates, input, laravel-blade, sanitization

Does the blade template (applicable to Laravel 5.4) input field, for example, `{!! Form::text($name, $value, []) !!}` escapes the input data? I want to escape the input data for malicious tags/code. The tag `{!! !!}` is meant to NOT escape the data while the [packagecontrol.io](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LaravelCollective%20HTML%20Form%20Snippets) describes the input fields with the same tag style `{!! abcd !!}`. Hence, the question, which is correct for Laravel 5.4 blade template format?

All the form's input data is further sanitized using regex inside the controller before insertion into db. Is it a proper practice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [laravel escaping all HTML in blade template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26023823/laravel-escaping-all-html-in-blade-template)

Comment: I am of the opinion, the answers are not clear as far as Laravel 5.4 version concerned.  Most Blogs and tutorials are for the older version.

Answer (score 0):

use this `{{ }}` to escape the "input data for malicious tags/code"

or

use this, `{!! !!}` to avoid escapes