# How to display data without showing html tags

Tags: laravel, tinymce

i'm using TINYMCE editor and when i show data from database it shows me the HTML tags

**hello evryone** 
good morning $$$

my code

```
      <div>
      {{ $actualites->description }}
      </div>
```

Comment: never heard of a "HTML balise" what is that?

Comment: HTML tags i mean sorry

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Escaping All HTML in Blade Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26023823/laravel-escaping-all-html-in-blade-template)

Answer (score 4):

Blade `{{ }}` escapes html to not do that use the `{!! !!}` notation

```
{!!$actualites->description!!}
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
{{strip_tags($actualites->description)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use

{!! isset($actualites->description) ? $actualites->description : '' !!}