# Displaying database entry with line break

Tags: php, laravel-5

I add the data with html special tags like `<br>` but when I retrieve data from database this shows ( `Welcome to this <br> Website` ). It does not break the line.

```
<h1>{{nl2br($image->heading)}}</h1>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Try `<h1>{!! $image->heading !!}</h1>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Escaping All HTML in Blade Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26023823/laravel-escaping-all-html-in-blade-template)

Comment: Be careful of using `{!! ... !!}` everywhere. It has a very specific purpose and should only be used on data you trust.